# ¿Recuperar el texto de un EditText en un DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy trabajando con DialogFragment para poder mostrar un cuadro de dialogo donde solicito dos datos que se capturan mediante dos EditText, el progblema es cuando quiero recuperar lo que se escriba en esos EditText, como puedo recuperar el contenido de esos EditText:

Esta es mi clase DialogFragment:

```
public class Dialogo extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private ArrayList<Registro_parqueo> lista;
    private String archivo = "parquimetro.obj";
    View view;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    onClickGuardarPersona();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Dialogo.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

public void onClickGuardarPersona() {
    try{

        EditText matricula = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
        EditText clientesillo = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cliente);

        ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(getActivity().openFileOutput(archivo, MODE_PRIVATE));
        objOutput.writeObject(new Registro_parqueo(matricula.getText().toString(),clientesillo.getText().toString()));
        objOutput.close();

    }catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al guardar el parqueo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Y aqui es donde llamo el cuadro de dialogo:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class listaparqueos extends Fragment {


    public listaparqueos() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listaparqueos, container, false);
        //Button presiona =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonq);
        FloatingActionButton crear = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.flotador);
        crear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickAlerta(v);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    **public void onClickAlerta(View view){
        //Dialogo.alerta(this,view).show();
        Dialogo dialogo = new Dialogo();
        dialogo.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "confirmaciÃ³n");**



       }
    }
```

Asi se ve el cuadro de dialogo de donde quiero recuperar los EditText:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el siguiente código puede ayudarte con tu problema:

```
public class dialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private String archivo = "parquimetro.obj";
    private ArrayList<Registro_parqueo> lista;
    View view;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        final EditText matricula = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
        final EditText clientesillo = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.cliente);
        builder.setView(MyView)
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        onClickGuardarPersona(matricula.getText().toString(),clientesillo.getText().toString());

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Dialogo.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String cliente) {
        try{

            ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(getActivity().openFileOutput(archivo, MODE_PRIVATE));
            objOutput.writeObject(new Registro_parqueo(matricula,cliente));
            objOutput.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al guardar el parqueo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Antes de pasarle la view al Builder del Dialog, captura los edittext que necesitas y envíalos como parametros a tu método.

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Crea variables de clase para tus EditText:

```
private EditText matricula;
private EditText clientesillo;
```

Obten la referencia en la variable:

```
  //EditText matricula = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
  //EditText clientesillo = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cliente);
  matricula = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
  clientesillo = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cliente)
```

de esta forma entonces puedes obtener el texto de tus EditText en cualquier parte de tu clase:

```
matricula.getText().toString()
clientesillo.getText().toString()
```